# How to do File System Task in SSIS depending on Result of Data Flow

Tags: ssis

I'm writing a (what I thought to be a) simple SSIS package to import data from a CSV file into a SQL table.

On the Control Flow task I have a Data Flow Task. In that Data Flow Task I have

- a Flat File Source "step",
- followed by a Data Conversion "step",
- followed by a OLE DB destination "step".

What I want to do is to move the source CSV file to a "Completed" folder or to a "Failed" folder based on the results of the Data Flow Task.

I see that I can't add a File System step inside the Data Flow Task, but I have to do it in the Control Flow tab.

My question is how do I do a simple thing like assign a value to a variable (I saw how to create variable and assign them a value at the bottom pane of Data Tools (2012)) depending of if the "step" succeeds or fails?

Thanks!

*(You can tell by my question that I'm an SSIS rookie - and don't assume I can write a C# script, please)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used VB or C# scripts to accomplish this myself. Since you do not want to use scripts I would recommend using a different path for the project to flow. Have your success path lead to moving the file to completed and failure path lead to moving the file to failed. This keeps it simple and accomplishes what you are looking for.

[image]

Comment: I can't find a "step" under the data flow tab to do that.

Comment: This has to be done in control flow. It accomplishes the goal of moving the file based on the result of the data flow task. Why do you want it done inside of the data flow task?

Comment: How do I know at the end of my OLE DB tasks if it failed or not? I shows only 1 arrow coming out of it: green.

Comment: Sorry, I just saw it. You first connect the arrow, and then right click on it so define failure, success. Thanks!